# Error appending to list according to state of bool

Tags: python, geopy

I am using 2 different libraries and running addresses through them. First i'm using geopy to clean and geocode addresses. Then i'm running the address through pygeocoder to see if the output is a valid address. If the output is valid, i'm appending the address to a list, which I will be returning later. If not, i'm appending "Can not be cleaned 
" (this is a flask application).

Even if the address is valid, and the valid_address function of pygeocoder is returning true, the address isn't being appended to the list for some reason. It is appending "Can not be cleaned 
" every time.

Here is my code:

```
if g.geocode(address).valid_address:
    cleaned.append((str(address) + ", " + str(zipcode.lstrip()) +
                        ", " + str(clean.latitude) + ", " + str(clean.longitude)) + '<br>')
    success += 1
else:
    cleaned.append('Can not be cleaned <br>')
        fail += 1
except AttributeError:
    cleaned.append('Can not be cleaned <br>')
    fail += 1
except ValueError:
    cleaned.append('Can not be cleaned <br>')
    fail += 1
except GeocoderTimedOut as e:
    cleaned.append('Can not be cleaned <br>')
    fail += 1
```

What do you folks think i'm doing wrong?

Comment: This partial code seems fine. You should provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem.

I wasn't giving pygeocoder enough information. My address was in the format of street number street name. By appending the city to the end of the address and THEN validating it I solved the problem.

Unfortunately, pygeocoder works through Google Maps, which has a relatively low request limit.